# Using custom fields in freemarker

Tags: freemarker, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to print custom field in PDF template, got from a saved search with the naming syntax Bank Name(Custom). How to use this name in the freemarker pdf template ? I am not able to fetch the value using any of the below : subs.bankname where subs is the result of the saved search.

Answer (score 1):

A NetSuite custom field is prefixed with "cust" (ie. custrecord, custentity, custbody, etc), so you need to find out the correct field's id in order to display it using the Freemarker syntax. Also, as "subs" is the result of a Saved Search, you might need to interact with all rows.

In your case it would be something like (to display the first row):

```
${subs[0].cust_bankname}
```

Or the following to interact with all rows:

```
<#list subs as sub>     
    ${sub.cust_bankname}
</#list>
```

I hope it helps.